# Ajax in Laravel Search function is not working

Tags: ajax, laravel

right now it is not showing any data;

**console:**`finished loading: GET "http://todolist.local/teachers/search?text=a".`

i am trying to show result in tbody, when user types something in search.

**Ajax code:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#searchname').on('keyup', function(){
                var text = $('#searchname').val();
                $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        url: 'teachers/search',
                        data: {text: $('#searchname').val()},
                        success:function(data){
$('tbody').html(data);
}
                });
        });
});
</script>
```

**web.php:**

```
Route::get('/search', 'TeachersController@ajaxsearch');
```

**Search Controller:**

```
public function ajaxsearch(){
$searchname = Input::get ( 'searchname' );
  if($searchname != ""){
  $teacher = Teacher::where ( 'efirst', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchname . '%' )->paginate(10);
  return response()->json($teacher);
}
}
```

**view:**

```
<div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="searchname" name="searchname" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search..." >
                   <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">Search</span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Is your route into a route group with **teachers**  prefix ?

Comment: yes, it is like that

Comment: are you sure `$searchname` is not equal to " " ?

Comment: yes it is not empty when i type something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This should do the trick**.

HTML:

```
  <div id="datasearch"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#searchname').on('keyup', function(){
        $.get('/teachers/search/'+$(this).val(), function(response){
            $('#datasearch').html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function ajaxsearch(string $value = null){
    return $value ? Teacher::whereRaw("UPPER(efirst) LIKE '%".strtoupper($value)."%'")->paginate(10) : [];
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/teachers/search/{value?}', 'TeachersController@ajaxsearch');
```

> **VERSION AFTER CHAT**

HTML:

```
  <ul id="datasearch"></ul>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var $datasearch=$('#datasearch');
    $('#searchname').on('keyup', function(){
        $.get('/teachers/search/'+$(this).val(), function(teachers){
            $datasearch.empty();
            for (var i=0; i<teachers.length; i++){
                $datasearch.append('<li>'+teachers[i].efirst+' <a href="/teachers/edit/'+teachers[i].id+'">edit</a></li>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
public function ajaxsearch(string $value = null){
    return $value ? Teacher::select('id','efirst')->whereRaw("UPPER(efirst) LIKE '".strtoupper($value)."%'")->offset(0)->limit(10)->get() : [];
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/teachers/search/{value?}', 'TeachersController@ajaxsearch');
```

Comment: if i type a. it shows few teachers, but if i type b or any other letter it shows nothing

Comment: table:  <table class="table table-striped" >
     <thead>

     </thead>
     <tbody>

     

     </tbody>
    </table>

Comment: I think is because the casesensitive.

Comment: I've changed the query to be case insensitive. Try now and let me know.

Comment: can you please tell how i can show result in div? instead of table? i think issue might be in table.

Comment: Anyway, you should do something with your data before pushing it to the body!

Comment: sorry, but nothing is showing when i type any character in search.
console: XHR finished loading: GET "http://todolist.local/teachers/search/a".

Comment: and this route is full of json data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200115/discussion-between-vixed-and-iscpreee).

Answer (score 0):

do you know about error function in jquery ajax?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#searchname').on('keyup', function(){
                var text = $('#searchname').val();
                $.ajax({
                        type:"GET",
                        url: 'teachers/search',
                        data: {text: $('#searchname').val()},
                        success:function(data){$('tbody').html(data);},
                        error:function(jqXHR){alert(jqXHR.status);} 
                });
        });
});
```

You can try this,it will show error if there is some and text should be in inverted commas as it is a key value pair.

Comment: see my edit jqXHR.status will show status code it got in response from status code you can diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your search controller you are accessing wrong input name. It should be like this

```
public function ajaxsearch(){
$searchname = Input::get ( 'text' );
  if($searchname != ""){
  $teacher = Teacher::where ( 'efirst', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchname . '%' )->paginate(10);
  return response()->json($teacher);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, just go to the URL manually and enter parameters. 
    http://todolist.local/teachers/search?text=a 
If you get any response. It's mean your PHP working good.

If you get an error, you are using the GET method. Please pass the variable argument in Route

```
Route::get('/search/{searchName}', 'TeachersController@ajaxsearch');
```

and please correct your controller

```
public function ajaxsearch($searchname){
   if($searchname != ""){
       $teacher = Teacher::where ( 'efirst', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchname.'%' )->paginate(10);
       return response()->json($teacher);
   }
}
```

Second, Please $.get method in Jquery for GET Method AJAX

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#searchname').on('keyup', function(){
           var text = $('#searchname').val();
            $.get(urlHere, function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
     });
</script>
```

See your console tab, If you get response

Comment: that's mean there's issue with your query. See if teachers table got any result. if table got result. you should test it with Teacher::all();